# Why "LANG=C"? (not D or E or F)

Tags: linux, localization, locale

In order to turn off localisation features one should set the LANG environment variable to "C".

Why "C"? Where did it come from?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the [C programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), the locale name `C` “specifies the minimal environment for C translation” ([C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §7.11.1.1; the principle has been the same since at least the 1980s). As most operating systems are written in C, especially the Unix-inspired ones where locales are set through the `LANG` and `LC_xxx` environment variables, `C` ends up being the name of a “safe” locale everywhere.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_02) specifies that both `C` and `POSIX` must be valid locale names, with the same neutral settings.